# Get Error : Firestore: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation. But I have already signed in

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I have this problem and try to fix with all  solutions I had found,but still not works. My rules in firebase cloud firestore is :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write : if auth != null ;
    }
  }
}
```

And I had already enable Sign-in Method Anonymously.

#### Android

`android/build.gradle`:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

`android/app/build.gradle`:

```
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
```

`Testing.js`:

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then(()=>{
        firebase.app().firestore().collection('Hello').doc('hello').set({
          id:'fadsa'
        }).catch((err)=>{
          alert(err);
        })
      })
```

---

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
  }
 }
}
```

change to this

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: request.auth worked, just auth did not, thank you! :)

Comment: This works for all types of authentication methods (including anonymous auth!)

Answer (score 24):

This is an issue because of the rules that your DB currently has. Please check both datebases, Realtime and Firestore.

As in general, having full security rules or any other rule that is not complitely understood by RD or CF logic will get you that error everytime.

```
> // Full security
> 
> {   "rules": {
>     ".read": false,
>     ".write": false   } }
```

in Firestore you can configurate that as the following:

```
> service cloud.firestore {   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     match /{document=**} {
>       allow read: if auth != null;
>       allow write: if auth != null;
>     }   } }
```

For more examples you can see:
https://gist.github.com/codediodeio/6dbce1305b9556c2136492522e2100f6
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: For me, it `request.auth` worked

Answer (score 15):

If you don't use authentication inside your app and only used the Firebase Firestore. So you can change it simply like this.

***Change This***

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
   }
  }
 }
```

***Into This***

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
   }
  }
 }
```

And last don't forget to publish these changes in order to save it.

**If you have specified through timeStamp**

If you have specified your Firestore rules through timeStamp then simply increase the length of duration of time.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if
    request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 3, 14);;
   }
  }
 }
```

**Note:** It is just for practicing and playing with Firestore data. If you want to build a production-level app then be sure to securely define your Firestore rules.

Answer (score 5):

Just want to add that this error can also happen if you enabled "App check" in Firebase and enforced the checking of the App check token but the token is missing in the requests.
[image]

In that case, you need to add the plugin [firebase_app_check](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_app_check).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error with my flutter application on Android Stuido and when I check the rules I saw there was a time limitation for allowing read and write operations. So I just extended the time period as below:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {

match /databases/{database}/documents {

match /{document=**} {

  allow read, write: if

      request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 9, 29);

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out, this can also happen if you have a function that runs (can be periodic) it ran after you are signed out.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, I struggled a lot because I missed  "No App Check token for request." warning.

If you enforced Cloud Firestore on app check, must configure, unenforce or add token. [firebase appcheck]

Answer (score -1):

This error was also occurring for me because I was testing my app using an internal test track and I need to enable a 'test API response' for App Check in the Google Play console. I also added my SHA256 fingerprint of my app from Google Play console into the Firebase console.

Answer (score -1):

You can into FirestoreDatabase, then update timestamp. Let the timestamp longer, then click on Develop and test.

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // This rule allows anyone with your Firestore database reference to view, edit,
    // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
    // your rules
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2025, 8, 9);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not good practise even development. Next devs may bloat their mind for detect an issue.

Answer (score -1):

For those encountering issues with the Firebase emulator, it's important to note that in the root folder where the emulator stores its data, there is a file named `firestore.rules`. Update the rules there just as you would for Firestore in the cloud.

Answer (score -5):

Update your rules file on Firestore console.
Set permission to read and write to true.

Comment: Do not do this, it is not secure and will allow anyone to write to your database